# Rails3 and Heroku: Sending Emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, heroku

I have deployed my Beta App to Heroku and am reading their articles about sending emails. I don't imagine I will be generating more then 100 per day. There seems to be 2 routes they suggest:

1) their sendgrid add-on [Article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp#sending_email_from_rails)

2) using gmail [Article](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/11/9/tech_sending_email_with_gmail/)

3) I have my own non-rails web hosting package - could I use this?

Does anyone have experience of using either of these? Which is considered better/easier to manage?

Comment: Have good experience using sendgrid. Simple to set up, reliable and convenient.  I believe, #3 also will be Ok or even better (you can tweak your MTA as you wish, in case it is VPS), in case it is shared hosting you should try it out to know exactly.

Comment: I found this link which helped me decide which solution to use - it might help others too [Read Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798141/sendgrid-vs-postmark-vs-amazon-ses-and-other-email-smtp-api-providers)

Comment: Still haven't managed to get Sendgrid wprking with Heroku. Neither companies can offer any useful help about how to use their services!! Very annoying....

Comment: @taro how did you sent up Sendgrid exactly? I have been onto Heroku and Sendgrid and neither can give me advice as to how to get it working?

Comment: I've set ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings in the config/environments/production.rb and it's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Heroku I would recommend Sendgrid over the Gmail solution. Sendgrid is well integrated and you won't touch the 200 emails limit.

Currently, I use both: Sendgrid with CommunityGuides on Heroku and Gmail for local testing. Sendgrid was painless to set up.

Comment: That's a great guide you have written there... wish I had found it 2 days ago!! Question are you sure that the Sendgrid user details go into the app/config/environments/production.rb file and not app/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb ?

Comment: Well, I have Gmail-settings in development.rb and the Sendgrid-setting in production.rb. Seems right to me, what do you think?

Comment: Did you set up Action Mailer or install the Mail gem to get it working? As I understand the instructions.... you just upload your app on Heroku and install the Sendgrid add-on and that should be it - except it doesn't work?

Comment: No gem, just the configuration in production.rb (this is the setup of ActionMailer) and the sendgrid add-on on Heroku [in one of the earlier articles is the configuration of Gmail, you might want to try if it works with Gmail or if the problem is in your code sending emails and not the configuration]

Comment: I removed the link because it's going to a parked domain with ads. Let's use the official Heroku link instead:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid

Comment: Thx, did not pay for the domain anymore ;) - content is still at http://communityguides.heroku.com/, however, it is unsupported.